# Understanding "hide nav-bar on scroll" code - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, dom-events

I am learning JS and I have a test page where I practice my new "discoveries".

I followed a tutorial on Youtube ([Here the link if somebody's interested](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMB0EW4u9TeFRfGrnQV2c2Q)) on how to hide/show the nav bar based on scrolling event. I applied it to my test page and of course it works well as you can see from the snippet, but I am having some trouble understanding 2 particular points. Hopefully somebody can explain them with "poor" words.

So, **here the JS code for the *scrolling event***

```
const header = document.querySelector('header');
let prev = window.pageYOffset;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  let current = window.pageYOffset;
  if(prev < current){
    header.classList.add('hide');
  }
  else {
    header.classList.remove('hide');
    }

    prev = current;

})
```

**Point n°1**

- In the **IF statement**, how `let prev;` knows that is smaller than `let current;` if there's no values assigned? I tried to think of this like "*when I scroll up, the portion of the viewport that went up, is smaller than the portion of the screen that is currently displayed.*". This "theory" works, but only until the portion of the content scrolled up is bigger than the actual portion of content displayed. Once this point is reached, my "theory" doesn't make sense anymore.

**Ponit n°2**

- Why the need of the last statement: `prev = current;` ? I noticed that **if I don't write** that last statement, the nav bar will **hide** when I scroll up, but when I scroll down it will **not show** anymore.

**The snippet**

```js
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
  burger.classList.toggle('hide');
  xicon.classList.toggle('active');
});

const xicon = document.querySelector('.xicon');
xicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
  xicon.classList.toggle('active');
  burger.classList.toggle('hide');
})



const header = document.querySelector('header');
let prev = window.pageYOffset;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  let current = window.pageYOffset;
  if(prev < current){
    header.classList.add('hide');
  }
  else {
    header.classList.remove('hide');
    }

    prev = current;

})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logoandicon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: powderblue;
  padding: .7em 0;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: .5em;
}

.burger {
  margin-right: 1em;
  z-index: 2;
}

.burger.hide {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: verdana;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

nav {
  padding: 1em 0;
  line-height: 2em;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: none;
}

nav.active {
  display: block;
}

.xicon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  display: none;
}

.xicon.active {
  display: block;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
}

header.hide {
  display: none;
}

main {
  padding-top: 4em;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <div class="logoandicon">
      <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
      <img src="menu.svg" class="burger" width="30px" alt="burger-icon">
      <img src="xicon.svg" class="xicon" width="27px" alt="x-icon">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ut, animi iure sequi voluptatem maiores, aspernatur tempora, ipsa tempore, voluptate sint. Maiores quos inventore cumque reiciendis iusto illum, aut quam, suscipit temporibus veniam. Reprehenderit distinctio velit eveniet blanditiis, animi optio voluptas dolores repellendus ad itaque veritatis. Expedita deserunt, ab dolor accusamus sequi eum optio. Fuga dolorum, quod qui laboriosam iure molestiae magnam explicabo! Accusamus, alias, non. Eius voluptas in aspernatur natus illo et possimus optio, cupiditate saepe quisquam totam laboriosam ullam nihil consequatur rem earum ratione perspiciatis. Quo impedit ipsum assumenda suscipit unde inventore dolores quas? Ipsa aliquam sapiente rerum sit autem magni ad dolore iste vero optio saepe, impedit eveniet suscipit, deserunt. Modi architecto laudantium placeat beatae repellat harum deleniti facere deserunt officia unde mollitia error praesentium, sunt fugit recusandae soluta facilis earum voluptatem libero consectetur illum debitis quos! Odit unde, quo non blanditiis vitae aperiam obcaecati provident praesentium quas qui, veritatis enim accusamus iusto rerum harum porro maxime sit amet cum odio suscipit ipsum nulla adipisci. Totam consectetur quas ipsa. Natus officiis, eveniet reprehenderit neque rem sint eum, ratione, numquam blanditiis nisi culpa repudiandae nemo beatae. Ea cum officiis vel, sed distinctio, voluptatibus quibusdam! Soluta voluptate, atur tempora, ipsa tempore, voluptate sint. Maiores quos inventore cumque reiciendis iusto illum, aut quam, suscipit temporibus veniam. Reprehenderit distinctio velit eveniet blanditiis, animi optio voluptas dolores repellendus ad itaque veritatis. Expedita deserunt, ab dolor accusamus sequi eum optio. Fuga dolorum, quod qui laboriosam iure molestiae magnam explicabo! Accusamus, alias, non. Eius voluptas in aspernatur natus illo et possimus optio, cupiditate saepe quisquam totam laboriosam ullam nihil consequatur rem earum ratione perspiciatis. Quo impedit ipsum assumenda suscipit unde inventore dolores quas? Ipsa aliquam sapiente rerum sit autem magni ad dolore iste vero optio saepe, impedit eveniet suscipit, deserunt. Modi architecto laudantium placeat beatae repellat harum deleniti facere deserunt officia unde mollitia error praesentium, sunt fugit recusandae soluta facilis earum voluptatem libero consectetur illum debitis quos! Odit unde, quo non blanditiis vitae aperiam obcaecati provident praesentium quas qui, veritatis enim accusamus iusto rerum harum porro maxime sit amet cum odio suscipit ipsum nulla adipisci. Totam consectetur quas ipsa. Natus officiis, eveniet reprehenderit neque rem sint eum, ratione, numquam blanditiis nisi culpa repudiandae nemo beatae. Ea cum officiis vel, sed distinctio, voluptatibus quibusdam! Soluta voluptate, non facilis?</h1>
  </main>


<script src="main.js">

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try my best to explain it and then provide commented out code.

It's not exactly the height of the viewport, window.pageYOffset calculates how far down you've scrolled from the top of the window. When you load the page, that number is 0. I suggest checking out [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset)

Then when you scroll, what was your current offset is set to prev and your new offset is set to current. You can try to `console.log(current, prev)` and see how it changes as you scroll up and down. When both prev and current have values, they get compared and if `current > prev`, it shows the element.

`prev = current` is what takes care of saving your previous offset so there's something to compare your new current value to.

```
const header = document.querySelector("header");
let prev = window.pageYOffset; // 0 when page loads, otherwise stores previous 'current' value

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  let current = window.pageYOffset; // your current offset from the top of the document

  // Add console.log(current, prev) here if you want to see how the offset changes, you'll notice that prev value is always smaller when you scroll down and bigger when you scroll up

  if (prev < current) {
    header.classList.add("hide");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  prev = current; // Set current variable to prev variable so there's something to compare
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. Is there an easy inprovment to this code to make the nav bar hide only when I've scrolled let's say 50px? I tried putting 50 in the if statement, but doesn't work

Comment: @marcomarco If I understand it right, you'll need a variable to store the offset in, but only when scrolling up and then compare your current variable to that when scrolling down. There's really no space for that in the comments so I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Senatrius/pen/jOqYjBQ?editors=0011) and left a few comments for you to follow

Comment: So nice of you! Thanks a lot, really! :)

Comment: @marcomarco Sure thing :) I actually learned it at the same time, too. I was tempted to just post how to do it so it just works with offset from the top of the page but not anywhere, but then I though "I know I've seen apps and some pages do it before so it can't be that hard". Did take a bit of experimentation for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Point n°1 - When the page loads the `pageYOffset` value is assigned to `prev` variable and a scroll event listener is activated. So when you scroll the current `pageYOffset` value is assigned to `current` variable and then it is compared to the `prev` variable. So as the condition says that if `prev` value is lesser than `current` then hide the navbar else show the nav bar.
Example - When the page loads, the value of `prev` will be assigned to 0. And when you scroll it will be greater than 0.

Point n°2 - Every time you scroll, the event will run the function. So when you scroll down the `current` value will get updated every time.So using `prev = current` you are storing the `current` value to the `prev` value. This lets the user to get the scrollbar, once he/she scrolls up.
Example - User scrolls down, the value of `current` is stored to `prev`. Let assume it as `current = 220` and it is stored in `prev`. So when the user scrolls up the `current` value will be 215. So the `prev` will be greater than `current` and navbar is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand [What is `window.pageYOffset` and how is work](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_pagexoffset.asp#:%7E:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,These%20properties%20are%20read%2Donly.) before explain your code.If you want to more customize other event in javascript, you must learn [`window`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp) and [addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp#:%7E:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,a%20scrollbar%20for%20an%20element.).When you have been learn, you will clear what these code work and you can do alot of thing with scroll in javascript.

You can use `console.log(SomeThing)` for debug in javascript.And then you can check step by step. Example:

```
const header = document.querySelector('header');

let prev = window.pageYOffset;
console.log("Start State for prev:" + prev); //debug for initial point

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){

let current = window.pageYOffset;
console.log("Current State for current:" + current); //debug for current point when you scroll

// you will see which condition is happen now 
// when you start scroll down "prev" is always smaller than "current".So condition is true, header will hide.
// when you scroll up "prev" is always smaller than "current".So condition is true, header will hide.

if(prev < current){
    header.classList.add('hide');
}
else {
    header.classList.remove('hide');
}

//But you want to show scroll up, you need to put current to prev.
prev = current;

})
```

`window.pageYOffset` return for some point start from 0. When you scroll down, `window.pageYOffset` return point is increase.When you scroll up `window.pageYOffset` return point is decrese.Because you use `window.addEventListener` for scroll if you don't use within scroll event. `window.pageYOffset` return point will not change.Therefore,`prev` value will fix because it have call one time. `current` value will be changing when use scroll.When you understand above code working, you can check the following answer for your points.

Point n°1

First time, you call these javascript, `prev` get some value.let say `prev` get '0'. It will be fix. `current` get some value the same with `prev`. So, condition is false. `header` will not hide. When you scroll down, `current` value is increase. `prev` value is the same. So, condition is true. `header` will hide.When you scroll up `current` value is decrease. `prev` value is the same.When `current` is changed to '0' value.Condition is false, `header` will not hide.

Ponit n°2

You want to unhide when you scroll up. You need to put `prev` value to higher than `current`.Scroll up is decrease. Let `current` is '10', `prev` value assign is '10'.Next time, `current` will decrese '9'. `prev` is '10'.Condition is false.`header` will not hide.Therefore, you need to assign `current` to `prev`.